# How to access element(s) and Remove a spefiic Class rooted within the DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

stackoverflow is new to me and this is my first post :]

Could someone please advise the best way to create JQuery code for the following objective?

1. Objective: I need a way to remove the CLASS 'active' from a nav element when it is active:

[image]

2. I have attempted to create some JQuery code which would locate the NAV element which contains the class 'Active' which in turn would also remove the given class from the selected nav element. Please refer to the following image: 
   [image]

Thanks for your help! sorry for the poor post formatting

Comment: please don't link the code.  include the relevant portions of code with your question.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please post your code within your question, and if you have a demo also include a snippet demo.

Comment: You probably need to have another class name for that element, just to always have a class name to use as a selector. And If you just want to remove the class `active` ONLY when the image is active (have it back after that) use `toggleClass` instead of `removeClass`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome!

1. `$('#btnDiv').toggleClass('active');` should fit your needs.
2. `$( "#dataTable tbody tr" ).on( "click", function() {
   // handler
   });` create a handler on your click event here.

Comment: Thanks all, appreciate the help!